# Is it possible to add hit detection to elements in a canvas? - Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, canvas, windows-phone, detection

I'm in the process of creating an app for Windows Phone 8.1, and it involves a canvas element. I'm spawning shapes onto the canvas element and the 'player' shape is controllable via accelerometer.

What I want to know is, can I add a hit test to each rectangle so that when the 'player' shape goes over a rectangle it will trigger an event? I'm adding rectangles using the following code:

```
public void addEnemy()
    {
        double canvasWidth = ballBox.ActualWidth;
        double canvasHeight = ballBox.ActualHeight;
        if(i >= 20){

        }
        else {
            Random rand = new Random();
            x = rand.Next(0, (int)canvasWidth - 50);
            y = rand.Next(0, (int)canvasHeight - 50);
            Rectangle rec = new Rectangle();
            rec.Width = 20; rec.Height = 20;
            rec.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Red);
            rec.StrokeThickness = 5;
            rec.Tag = "Rec" + i.ToString();


            displayCanvas.Children.Add(rec);
            Canvas.SetLeft(rec, x);
            Canvas.SetTop(rec, y);
            i++;
    }
```

This addEnemy function is called every second using a timer.

Thanks.

Comment: Not an answer because I don't know - but https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br243041.aspx